# How to Remove Blooger post snippet code from below template

Tags: javascript, html, css, templates, blogger

Here is my blog URL: https://veganbeautybox.blogspot.com/ and here are i posted full  Template code  https://pastebin.com/GXuPFKzH

**Post show with Snippet** & But I want to show full post in home page . Please guide me - which code will be remove.

[blog home page image][1]

Answer (score 0):

You have to replace `<data:post.snippet/>` with `<data:post.body/>` inside `<b:includable id='post' >`